# Можно ли удаленно обновлять Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, автоматизация, обновление

Есть с полсотни ноутбуков, находящихся в выключенном состоянии на зарядке в тележках. Если ли рабочий способ их обновления, не доставая из тележек?
То есть:

- удаленное их включение
- логин под пользователем с паролем
- установка свежих обновлений
- перезагрузка столько раз, сколько понадобится
- выключение

Comment: Насколько эти ноутбуки современные? В каком году выпущены?

Comment: 2018-2019 годов выпуска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы ноутбук нормально охлаждался, он должен стоять на столе в открытом виде, и никакие предметы не должны закрывать ему выход воздуха.
2. Даже если на это наплевать, у вас есть вторая проблема, а именно - как включить ноутбук удаленно.

Wi-Fi не поддерживает wake-on-lan. Встроенный Ethernet есть не на всех ноутбуках. На тех ноутбуках, где он есть, не всегда есть поддержка wake-on-lan. Вероятность того, что какой-то USB-адаптер будет поддерживать WOL равна 0.

3. Значит, удаленно включить ноутбук практически невозможно.

Остается пробуждение по расписанию. Тут как повезет - если BIOS умный, то да, можно это настроить. Собственно само обновление в таком случае случится автоматически.

Если же BIOS глупый, то увы, без шансов.

*Если конечно у вас нету очумелых ручек, которые вколхозят в каждый ноут "ребутатор" из платы ESP-01 и простейшей прошивки.*

Comment: Но usb-устройства сами могут будить. У меня комп (правда, стационарный) сам из гибернации выходил, пока я в диспетчере устройств не запретил для мыши пробуждение компа.

Comment: @Qwertiy от мыши это разве сам? это мышь пошевелилась и разбудила

Comment: Многие ноутбуки вырубают порты USB при выключении. Наглухо выключают питание. 

Да, тут может повести с BIOS, в котором может быть опция, которая заставит BIOS не отключать питание USB + опция, которая опять же, поможет внешней карте (это такую еще найти надо!) пробудить ноут. 

Это все игры с вероятностями, надежного общего решения нет (кроме очумелых ручек)

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну отправил комп в гибернацию, дождался, пока всё выключится, ушёл из комнаты на 5 минут, вернулся, а он включен - для меня это вполне сам.

Comment: @Qwertiy трамвай проехал или соседи долбят и стол слегка трясётся. Такая же проблема,я поэтому теперь мышь выключаю перед гибернацией.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а у меня проводная, так что нашёл настройку. Но вообще идея была в том, что можно ноуту в usb сунуть какой-нибудь таймер, который сможет его будить.

Comment: @Qwertiy это возможно только при наличии поддержки такой штуки со стороны BIOS ноута. Тут очень важно уточнение, что у автора ноутбук - в ноутбуке нету большого смысла просыпаться от шевеления мышью, поэтому, вероятность встретить пункт "просыпаться при открытии крышки" гораздо больше чем "просыпаться при движении мышки"

Comment: @gbg, но если это будит физический таймер, то ему вовме не обязательно эмулировать мышь. Например, есть клавиатура. А может можно вообще какое-то кастомное устройство эмулировать типа подключения аппаратного ключа или вообще чего-то необычного.

Comment: Друзья, спасибо за ответ и за столь оживленную дискуссию!

Действительно, о первом самом пункте я не подумал. Охлаждение действительно важная вещь.

Просто проведение всех манипуляций при каждом обновлении Win10 довольно монотонно и трудозатратно (что самое важное). Очень неприятны ситуации, когда внезапно потребовавшиеся пару десятков ноутбуков начинают обновляться, лишая возможности их использования.

Comment: @Alexey, Спасибо за теплые слова! Если ответ вам полезен, воспользуйтесь стрелками и галкой, чтобы обозначить его.